# Response errors (403) for signalr labels recorded by Blazemeter for Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I recorded login and logoff requests using blazemeter. After the record nearly 10 request has been created by blazemeter, which some of them includes .../signalr/.../connectionToken labels.
when i run the test these labels return an error like [image: this] and [image: this].

the test included 10 users. The users have different username and passwords. The other labels (another from these signalr labels) return true.

So, i wonder now if i can disable these pages and not include in the tests? or
any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

- > if i can disable these pages and not include in the tests

  theoretically yes, you can ask around whether SignalR is in scope for performance testing and if not you could disable those, however I believe well-behaved JMeter test should act exactly like a real browser so if the real browser sends these requests to `.../signalr/.../connectionToken` - JMeter should also send them
- > or any solution for this issue

  I don't think you can record and successfully replay anything in [Web 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_2.0) times, the majority of web applications heavily use dynamic tokens for various reasons (saving client state, security, tracking, etc.). When you record the request you get a hard-coded value which can expire or invalidate by other means, you need to identify all the dynamic values like this SignalR token and perform [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start): the process of dynamic values extraction  from the previous responses using suitable JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and re-using them in next requests in form of [JMeter Variables or Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

  If you record the same user scenario second time and compare two resulting test plans all the request parameters which change will require correlation. There is also an [alternative recording option](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000271458-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder) which is capable of exporting recorded requests in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of dynamic parameters, see [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) for more details.

Comment: i am trying to solve the problem with blazemeter proxy recording. but it is not easy. i have been using blazemeter chrome plugin which was easy to use. But now i have read the links for proxy recorder. i cant progress. a page is open that is a proxy recording page. in another page i send requests to server. but in recording page captured URLS does not change. in recording page a proxy is avaliable. but i dont know what it is